# Why do different query values produce different index algorithms?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query and I have created indexes specially for this query. But I just discovered that if I use some particular values, the query stops being running fast, and does a full scan.

Here is the case of fast execution:

```
explain analyze SELECT                                          
                         v.valtr_id,                             
                         v.block_num,                            
                         v.from_id,                              
                         v.to_id,                                
                         v.from_balance::text,                   
                         v.to_balance::text                      
                 FROM value_transfer v                           
                 WHERE                                           
                         (v.block_num<=2748053) AND              
                         (                                       
                                 (v.to_id=639291) OR             
                                 (v.from_id=639291)              
                         )                                       
                 ORDER BY                                        
                         v.block_num DESC,v.valtr_id DESC        
                 LIMIT 1 

 Limit  (cost=23054.03..23054.03 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=1.464..1.465 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=23054.03..23068.94 rows=5964 width=30) (actual time=1.462..1.462 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_transfer v  (cost=144.85..23024.21 rows=5964 width=30) (actual time=1.397..1.437 rows=3 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((to_id = 639291) OR (from_id = 639291))
               Filter: (block_num <= 2748053)
               Heap Blocks: exact=3
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=144.85..144.85 rows=5964 width=0) (actual time=1.339..1.339 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_to_id_idx  (cost=0.00..40.42 rows=1580 width=0) (actual time=0.755..0.755 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_id = 639291)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_from_id_idx  (cost=0.00..101.45 rows=4384 width=0) (actual time=0.580..0.580 rows=2 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (from_id = 639291)
 Planning time: 0.499 ms
 Execution time: 1.556 ms
(15 rows)
```

But if I put the value `199658` as input to my query, it uses different search algorithm:

```
explain analyze SELECT                                          
                         v.valtr_id,                             
                         v.block_num,                            
                         v.from_id,                              
                         v.to_id,                                
                         v.from_balance::text,                   
                         v.to_balance::text                      
                 FROM value_transfer v                           
                 WHERE                                           
                         (v.block_num<=2748053) AND              
                         (                                       
                                 (v.to_id=199658) OR             
                                 (v.from_id=199658)              
                         )                                       
                 ORDER BY                                        
                         v.block_num DESC,v.valtr_id DESC        
                 LIMIT 1          ;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..6462.99 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=614109.855..614109.856 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using bnum_valtr_idx on value_transfer v  (cost=0.57..200845479.66 rows=31079 width=30) (actual time=614109.853..614109.853 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (block_num <= 2748053)
         Filter: ((to_id = 199658) OR (from_id = 199658))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 101190609
 Planning time: 0.515 ms
 Execution time: 614109.920 ms
(7 rows)
```

Why is this happening? I thought that once you have created the indexes for your query , the execution will take the same path always, but it is not the case. How can I make sure Postgres always uses the same algorithm in every search?

I even thought this happens because probably the indexes weren't built cleanly and rebuilt the main index:

```
postgres=> drop index bnum_valtr_idx;
DROP INDEX
postgres=>  CREATE INDEX bnum_valtr_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC);
CREATE INDEX
postgres=>
```

however, this didn't change anything.

My table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE value_transfer (
    valtr_id            BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    tx_id               BIGINT          REFERENCES transaction(tx_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_id            INT             REFERENCES block(block_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_num           INT             NOT NULL,
    from_id             INT             NOT NULL,
    to_id               INT             NOT NULL,
    value               NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    from_balance        NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    to_balance          NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    kind                CHAR            NOT NULL,
    depth               INT             DEFAULT 0,
    error               TEXT            NOT NULL
);

postgres=> SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'value_transfer';
 schemaname |   tablename    |      indexname      | tablespace |                                             indexdef                                             
------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | value_transfer | bnum_valtr_idx      |            | CREATE INDEX bnum_valtr_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC)
 public     | value_transfer | value_transfer_pkey |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX value_transfer_pkey ON public.value_transfer USING btree (valtr_id)
 public     | value_transfer | vt_tx_from_idx      |            | CREATE INDEX vt_tx_from_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (tx_id)
 public     | value_transfer | vt_block_num_idx    |            | CREATE INDEX vt_block_num_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num)
 public     | value_transfer | vt_from_id_idx      |            | CREATE INDEX vt_from_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (from_id)
 public     | value_transfer | vt_to_id_idx        |            | CREATE INDEX vt_to_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (to_id)
 public     | value_transfer | vt_block_id_idx     |            | CREATE INDEX vt_block_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_id)
(7 rows)

postgres=>
```

Comment: Try executing [`ANALYZE value_transfer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-analyze.html) then rerun the explains - did they change? Also, are there the same number of rows returned from each query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could could be that one value is in one column and visa versa. Regardless, an `OR` over different columns is notorious for causing performance problems because the query plan can only use one index, but the `OR` would require *two* indexes to be used to check both columns quickly, so one column will be checked using its index, but the other requires a scan.

The way around this problem is to break the query into a union.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT                                          
    valtr_id,                             
    block_num,                            
    from_id,                              
    to_id,                                
    from_balance::text,                   
    to_balance::text                      
  FROM value_transfer                         
  WHERE block_num<=2748053
  AND to_id=199658
UNION ALL
  SELECT                                          
    valtr_id,                             
    block_num,                            
    from_id,                              
    to_id,                                
    from_balance::text,                   
    to_balance::text                      
  FROM value_transfer                         
  WHERE block_num<=2748053
  AND from_id=199658
) x
ORDER BY block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC        
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks! I tried your query and the first half of it takes a lot of time. Tthe condition `to_id=199658` takes around 600 seconds, for a table of 100 million records.

Comment: ->  MergeAppend (cost=8155.05..16885.81 rows=2 width=30) (actual time=635127.559..635127.559 rows=1 loops=1)
         SortKey: v.block_num DESC, v.valtr_id DESC
         ->Limit  (cost=0.57..8731.28 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=634612.521..634612.521 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->Index Scan using bnum_valtr_idx on value_transfer v  (cost=0.57..211903060.23 rows=24271 width=30) (actual time=634612.519..634612.519 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (block_num <= 2748053)
                     Filter: (to_id = 199658)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 101303830

Comment: `select count(*) from value_transfer where to_id=199658;` returns 21357 rows

Comment: while `select count(*) from value_transfer where from_id=199658;` returns only 2566 rows. Could be this the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: I found the solution, I created a subquery to force Postgres to use indexes that I needed.

Comment: You can force Postgres to use an index by coding a hint. Maybe that would help too.